# Twilio CLI Error with Flex-Plugin (Requiring an older version)

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am getting the following error when trying to start a Flex Plugin:

Command to start:
`twilio flex:plugins:start`

error:

> The Flex Plugins CLI version installed is different from the version
> used by your plugin. The Plugins CLI version installed is 5.1.2 and
> the version used by your plugin is 5.0.3. Run the upgrade plugin
> command to use the installed version.

The Repo and Code I am using is [here](https://github.com/TwilioTraining/plugin-feathercorp-fx5).

Is there a way to install a specific version of `@twilio-labs/plugin-flex` from the Twilio CLI (i.e. 5.0.3) or is this error incorrect or can I change something from the repo clone to make it compatible with plugin-flex 5.1.2? I looked at the Twilio CLI options via --help but nothing stands out other then updating to the latest version which I am on (@twilio-labs/plugin-flex 5.1.2).

```
% twilio plugins:update --help
update installed plugins

USAGE
  $ twilio plugins:update

OPTIONS
OPTIONAL FLAGS
  -h, --help     show CLI help
  -v, --verbose

MORE INFO

--
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited my package.json and changed it there, under dependencies:

`"@twilio/flex-plugin-scripts": "5.1.2",` (it was 5.0.3)

Also, for some reason, the project was missing the appConfig.js in the public directory which I had to create, using:

appconfig.js

```
var appConfig = {
    pluginService: {
      enabled: true,
      url: '/plugins',
    },
    logLevel: 'info',
  };
```